# Core ML model conversion fails with "Unable to infer input name and dimensions"

Tags: python, ios, machine-learning, coreml

I am trying to make a Core ML model from Places205 - GoogLeNet, as described by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/).

I don't want to use the ready-made model by Apple, so I got the original model from this link: https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/model-details/Places205-GoogLeNet.txt

As per Apple's WWDC session we can convert that model using Coremltools. In their session we don't know which IDE they are using for Python coding but currently I am using Pycharm for Python coding.

Using the link to the model, we can get two things .caffemodel and .prototext. I tried to convert these using coremltools and received the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to infer input name and dimensions. Please provide a .prototxt file with 'Input' layer and dimensions defined.
```

So if Apple's given models are not converting then how we can say other open source model will work?

You can see my code base in attached screenshot.

How can this error be fixed?

[image]

Comment: You are probably using the wrong .prototxt file. Usually there is one called xxx_deploy.prototxt. Use that one instead.

Comment: But I got it from apple's site. They created their model from it so how it should be wrong? I got files from this link - http://places.csail.mit.edu/model/googlenet_places205.tar.gz

Comment: I used "deploy_places205.protxt" , it's not extension with ".prototext" but this time it works and compiles successfully. Thanks @MatthijsHollemans for your inputs. I will research more in this till creating own model.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a valid assumption to make that Apple created their own models using these tools. They may have created them some other way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Matthijs solved your core problem with his comment above, but I can expand on that for future people who encounter this with other models.

When converting a Caffe model to a .mlmodel file using Apple's coremltools, Apple's converter takes in both the binary .caffemodel (containing the model structure and weights), as well as a text-based .prototxt model description (which might have a little more context than the .caffemodel does).

Often, trained Caffe models will have a few different .prototxt files along with them (`deploy.prototxt`, `solver.prototxt`, `train.prototxt`), and you generally want to use the `deploy.prototxt` (or a similarly named prototxt).

Even if you do, you still may encounter an error about coremltools being "Unable to infer input name and dimensions". Caffe models don't have an explicit requirement to state the input dimensions the model will accept, so coremltools tries to infer that from a few different sources. If those sources are missing, you may need to edit them into the .prototxt yourself.

In the above-linked `deploy_places205.protxt`, this input size is specified by the following code at the top of the file:

```
input: "data"
input_dim: 10
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224
```

but you may also see the following in one of these .prototxt descriptions:

```
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 1
  dim: 3
  dim: 227
  dim: 227
}
```

If you have a .prototxt file that is missing this for its input, you could add either of the above right before the first `layer {` instance in the file. The dimensions are, in order: batch size (ignored by Core ML), color channels, image width, image height. You can adjust these to match what the network expects.

You may also need to verify that "data" is the input layer used by the model, so look for the first `layer {` instance and check that it says `bottom: "data"` within it. If the layer name is something different, you may need to either change it there or in your data layer name.

You may also need to set your data layer name in the coremltools converter to make sure it picks up the right one. For reference, here's the little Python script I use for converting a model like this:

```
import coremltools

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('mymodel.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt'),
                                                    image_input_names = "data",
                                                    is_bgr = True,
                                                    class_labels='labels.txt'
                                                   )


coreml_model.save('MyModel.mlmodel')
```

Comment: Thanks you brad Larson for more detailed answer. If we don't have labels.txt then coremltools works? I tried to convert one caffe model - https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw, and they don't have any labels. I got success to create my .mlmodel. But it doesn't work in Xcode. Is there any specific requirements for that?

Comment: @AmritTrivedi - I don't believe that you need the labels, they just serve to map numerical outputs to text labels. You can do that mapping yourself later (knowing that class 0 is "dog", class 1 is "cat", or whatever). The NSFW model is binary, so there's no need for labels there.

Comment: I'm trying to convert: http://dl.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel using https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt using this code:  coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt'))

Comment: Conversion succeeds, but VNCoreMLModel(for: bvlc_reference_caffenet().model) fails with this error:

Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=15 "The model does not have a valid input feature of type image"

How do we fix deploy.prototxt to make this work?

Comment: @PatrickBeard - Did you set `image_input_names = "data"` as one of the parameters for `coremltools.converters.caffe.convert()`, like I do above? You'll need that to tell Core ML that the `data` layer takes in images. You might also want to set `is_bgr = True`, like I do above, to get the colorspace to line up correctly.

Comment: Yes, and finally I also had to specify `class_labels = 'labels.txt'` to get actual results.

Comment: Really nicely explained, worked for me.Thanks Brad :)